# Select SQL Column

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-redshift, sql-query-store

I have column name `user.phonenumber`, and I want to apply a select query onto it.

like `select user.phonenumber from humans;`

> SQL error: ERROR: relation "user" does not exist [ErrorId: 1-628cb0d2-0897124f1720f36f3c6ae4ea]

Comment: try `select \`user.phonenumber\` from humans`

Comment: try this one `select user.phonenumber from humans as user`

Comment: @RiggsFolly when I tried 'user.phonenumber' the whole column filled with user.phonenumber instead of actual number

Comment: @RajuAhmed 'user.phonenumber' is the actual column name. it gives the error that I mention in question

Comment: Have you made sure that you are using backticks ` and not single quotes ' ?

Comment: try `select \`user.phonenumber\` from humans` They are BackTicks `\`` and NOT single quotes `'`

Comment: yes, I confirmed that I use backTicks not single quotes @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 0):

If `phonenumber` is the column name and `user` is the name of the table, then you either specify this table in the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT user.phonenumber from user;
```

or you need to add a `JOIN` to specify how `humans` is related with `user`. This depends on your data structure. The following code is just an example:

```
select user.phonenumber from humans 
  join user on humans.user_id = user.id;
```

If `user.phonenumber` is the actual field name in the `humans` table, then you have to surround the field name with backticks:

```
select `user.phonenumber` from humans;
```

By default the parser treats a a literal, here `user`, separated by a dot from the next literal, here `phonenumber`, as a table named followed by the column name. By wrapping it into backticks, you tell the SQL parser that the following string is a single name.

Make sure to use a backtick ` rather than the similar looking single quote '. A single quote denotes a string literal and will result in whatever you wrote within quotes.

Comment: No, Actually this is the column name. I migrated data from MongoDB to AWS Redshift. in Mongo user was the object

Comment: OK, my bad. Then you have to put the column name into backticks. I'll revise my answer.

Comment: So its a TYPO, we dont answer those, we comment and close the question as they are almost never any use to others, which of course is the main point of SO

Comment: Wouldn't it be helpful to others to know why the original query doesn't return the result the poster expected?